# Fiber-optic communication: Link length

Tags: networking, fiber, fibre-channel

I am trying to understand fiber optic communication over long distances:

Can optical fibre communication links be used for a length of 100km as well as 100000km without having to change sender and receiver equipment? What are physical limitations besides the typical loss of 0.2 dB/km?

Comment: What kind of link would you need that is 100000km?  That would be a fiber that goes around the earth at the equator 2.5 times.  But it is 1/4th the distance to the moon.

Comment: @Zoredache Tethered suborbital frikkin' *lasers*

Answer (score 4):

> Can optical fibre communication links be used for a length of 100km as
>   well as 100000km without having to change sender and receiver
>   equipment?

In short, no. Any fiber run of decent length is going to require specialized high-power laser optics on both ends as well as some sort of in-line amplification. These days, [EDFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_amplifier#Erbium-doped_fiber_amplifiers)s are typically used on very long-haul runs.

To clarify, short-haul runs and long-haul runs need different optics. If you tried to use short-haul optics on too long of a run, there will be too much attenuation and you'll never get link. Theoretically you could use long-haul optics on a shorter circuit, however you'd need optical attenuators on each end so you don't blow out the receivers.